# laravel array value in foreach loop another array value how to show

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

[image]

// controller code

```
    $mtest = mtest::with('mycourse')->get();
    //$mtest=$mtest->toarray();

    print_r($mtest);
```

[image]

//  controller code

```
    $mtest = mtest::with('mycourse')->get();
    $mtest=$mtest->toarray();

    print_r($mtest);
```

index.blade.php code

```
    @foreach($mtest as $us)
<tr>

  <td>{{$us->tname}}</td>
  **<td>{{$us->name}}</td>**
  <td>{{$us->course_id}}</td>
  <td>{{$us->qno}}</td>
  @endforeach
```

in the array a value in `[mycourse]=> array[0]=array(['id']`..... my question how to get `mycourse array value ->name= Ras exam` please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't transform toArray.
This should just do what you need.

```
<td>{{$us->mycourse->first()->name}}</td>
```

Last try

Comment: Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: If it works with ->first()->name, then you have to edit model  a bit.

Comment: thanks working nicely  may you please explain why use `first()` here

Comment: post please mycourse model code. If Mtest belongs to only one mycourse, you have to change model mycourse

Comment: ` public function mycourse()
    {
     return $this->hasMany('App\course','id','course_id');
    }`  model code

Comment: here I want to use  `paginate()` how to use, please explain

Comment: So... If mtest belongs to only one mycourse then: mtest model looks like public function mycourse() { return $this->belongsTo('App\Mycourse','id','course_id'); } and mycourse model looks like function mtest() { return $this->hasMany('App\Mtest','id','course_id'); }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213757/discussion-between-nikistag-and-gnziet).